# Host on Heroku a Gupshup ChatBot with Wit.ai

Tags: heroku, gupshup

I Would like to know if this is possible. I would like to host on my own Heroku Server my ChatBot and deploy it with Gupshup on my Website. I want to add Wit.ai to manage NLP.
Is it possible to do that ?
If it is, How can I do that ? DO you have a sample to test this solution ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the Callback option that Gupshup has. You can write your bot code and host it on the server then go to the Gupshup [dashboard](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/dashboard) and create a bot using the callback option as in the screenshot.
[image]
This URL will receive all the information like message from the user, type of message,unique id etc. which you need to read and then respond back to the same callback.

More details can be found in this [document](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/building-bot-outside-bot-builder-tool).